# Persistent Routes in 2008R2 - does this keep a static ARP cache or only L3 cache?

Tags: route

When using/defining persistent routes in windows 2008R2, what level of info is cached? Is this working at the ARP/MAC level? If a new router is put into play, but Layer 3 remains the same, would the persistent route still be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MAC address for the ip address wouldn't be persistent. If you changed the device that has the ip address in your static route then the host with the static route would have to resolve the ip address to the new MAC address.